# How to connect to Oracle 10g server from client machines

Tags: vb.net, oracle10g

I have installed Oracle 10g in one of my office's computer. I want to keep this as database server. I am developing a .net project which will communicate with the database server from client machine and from the server machine. I success to communicate with oracle from server machine but not from client machine using the .net project. The connection code is as follows:

```
Public OraConn As ADODB.Connection  
OraConn = New ADODB.Connection  
OraConn.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"  
OraConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=<my_database_name>;User ID=<my_user>;Password=<my_pass>;"  
OraConn.Open()
```

Please tell me step by step procedures how can I connect to my server database from my .net client program resides on client machine ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is to try and ping the port of the db in your server (if you are using windows you can use "telnet  ", see that you aren't blocked by any firewall rules in you server.

my second one is "Data Source="

if all fails, try reading this:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/cook_dotnet.html

Comment: what would be the Data Source String?

Comment: Your link helped me much more. Thanks for the info.